# Simple examples on how to use html2json

Tags: python, html, json

I am brand new to Python. I know about 2-weeks of it, so I don't understand a lot of what I am seeing online. I have to download HTML text from multiple similar pages and convert it to JSON. It must include the HTML links--it cannot just be the table contents. I have figured out how to use Beautiful Soup to download the code off a website, and I have been able to get the portions into a Python list of 547 similar groupings. There are 547 in this one file so far. The next step is to convert it to JSON. I have "a" and "tr" and "td" tags and "class" and "data-href" and "href" (attributes?) as well as text and links associated with those. I think html2json will work for me, but I cannot figure out how to use it. I installed it, and it is in my library. I understand how to do collect(html, template) to get it to convert ... but nowhere gives an explanation on how to do the template. I only found 2 pages that describe it with weird terms and no actual examples. I can't even find anything that explains whether template uses () or {} or [] or whether it does or does not have an = for assigning it. Can someone provide an example of a few lines of HTML and what the template actually looks like in Python? Here is my code so far:

```
page = requests.get(url)
page

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
soup

gs_results = soup.find_all('tr', class_= 'gsc_a_tr')
gs_results

gs_links = []
for i in gs_results:
    item = i
    gs_links.append(item)

template = I_HAVE_NO_IDEA_WHAT_GOES_HERE
collect(gs_links, template)
```

Comment: Python has native json library, which converts python objects (list, dict, primitive types) to JSON files natively: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: Thanks, but that page is far beyond my knowledge of Python. I only understand about 1/20 of it, and I didn't see where it can interpret HTML tags and attributes to do what I need. I did try "json.dumps(gs_links)" but it gave "TypeError: Object of type Tag is not JSON serializable". Again, I am extremely new at Python, so pages for experts do not make sense to me.

Comment: You are on the right track using BeatifulSoup. You can use it, to find parts of the HTML, either using XPath queries or walking through the DOM manually. You need to collect these information to regular python constructs, such as dictionaries, lists or other primitives. The native JSON library is capable of transforming any data, consisting only of these native types to JSON strings. If you need more help, or a working solution, please provide an exact statement of what you expect from the algorithm.

Comment: The code I am trying to use is described on https://pypi.org/project/html2json/ with the unexplained statement "template is the JSON of template loaded as Python objects." I see no explanation of what that means or an example of how to do it provided--at least, not in any way that makes sense to someone not expert in Python. I just need to know how to format "template" in my code.

Comment: There is a website where you can paste your HTML and get the JSON, so I know the template is not unique to each HTML entry. https://html2json.com I just need to know how to format the template. I expect it is something like "template = ???" but have no idea what the declaration should look like, where there might be [] or () or {} or what contents to include or anything else about it. I could not find any example of it.

Comment: I tried to post a sample of the HTML along with the JSON output from the website, but it is much too long to fit in a comment.

Comment: Please state in the original question, what exactly you need. What are the tags, that you are interested in? What are the attributes/content that you want to collect? JSON is a generic data-format. What kind of structure do you want it to have?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am going to go in a different direction. The html2json would have worked great, but I cannot afford more time trying to figure out what the website means when it poorly explains how to format the template variable. I am just going to convert the HTML list of tags to a list of strings and then use the replace feature to manually convert it to dictionary entries and turn it into JSON that way.